# Why is the process ID returned by pcntl_fork different from the process ID of what is actually running?

Tags: php

I'm using `pcntl_fork()` to spawn a child process. In the parent block of code, I record the process ID to a file, this should be the child process ID, right?

This process ID differs from what is actually running.

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();

if ($pid == -1) {
    die('could not fork');
} else if ($pid) {
    // we are the parent
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . "/update.pid", $pid);
    //pcntl_wait($status); //Protect against Zombie children
} else {
    $command = "php " . dirname(__FILE__) . "/my_script.php &";
    $output = shell_exec($command);
}
```

Comment: How do you know the child process ID is not correct? I hope you don't check the process ID of the php process you start in the `else` block...

Comment: I compared what was in `update.pid` with the output of `ps aux | grep php`

Comment: Is the code above the complete PHP code of your script? If no, please edit your question to include the full source code you have.

Comment: Maybe the child process is finishing before you do the `ps`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `shell_exec()` runs a shell process, and then it runs `php` in its own child. So you have the following process hierarchy:

```
- php -- original script
    - shell -- created by pcntl_fork() and shell_exec
        - php -- created by executing "php" in shell
```

The PID returned by `pcntl_fork()` is the second process.

You can tell the shell to use its own process to run the `php` command by using the `exec` command:

```
$command = "exec php " . dirname(__FILE__) . "/my_script.php";
```

However, if you want to do this, you can't use `&` at the end of the command. In order to run a command in the background, it has to be run in a new process, so the original shell can continue without waiting for it to finish.